# Preserve whitespaces when using split() and join() in python

Tags: python, join, split

I have a data file with columns like

```
BBP1   0.000000  -0.150000    2.033000  0.00 -0.150   1.77
```

and the individual columns are separated by a varying number of whitespaces.

My goal is to read in those lines, do some math on several rows, for example multiplying column 4 by .95, and write them out to a new file. The new file should look like the original one, except for the values that I modified.

My approach would be reading in the lines as items of a list. And then I would use `split()` on those rows I am interested in, which will give me a sublist with the individual column values. Then I do the modification, `join()` the columns together and write the lines from the list to a new text file.

**The problem is that I have those varying amount of whitespaces**. I don't know how to introduce them back in the same way I read them in. The only way I could think of is to count characters in the line before I split them, which would be very tedious. Does someone have a better idea to tackle this problem?

Comment: if the file is in a fixed format then using the same number of spaces can change column widths. You could use string formatting to preserve the file format e.g., `"{:4s} {:10.6f} {:10.6f} {:11.6f} {:5.2f} {:6.3f} {:6.2f}".format(*row)`, where `row = ["BBP1",   0.0,  -0.15, 0.95*2.033, 0.0, -0.15, 1.77]`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You want to use `re.split()` in that case, with a group:

```
re.split(r'(\s+)', line)
```

would return both the columns *and* the whitespace so you can rejoin the line later with the same amount of whitespace included.

Example:

```
>>> re.split(r'(\s+)', line)
['BBP1', '   ', '0.000000', '  ', '-0.150000', '    ', '2.033000', '  ', '0.00', ' ', '-0.150', '   ', '1.77']
```

You probably *do* want to remove the newline from the end.

Comment: To consistently handle whitespace at the beginning and/or end, a better pattern is `(\S+)`

Comment: @MikeT: the downside of that is that if there is no whitespace at the start or end you get an empty `''` string for those.

Comment: splitting `(\S+)` always has non-word strings at start and end, which is a predictable upside from my perspective.

Answer (score 9):

Other way to do this is:

```
s = 'BBP1   0.000000  -0.150000    2.033000  0.00 -0.150   1.77'
s.split(' ')
>>> ['BBP1', '', '', '0.000000', '', '-0.150000', '', '', '', '2.033000', '', '0.00', '-0.150', '', '', '1.77']
```

If we specify space character argument in split function, it creates list without eating successive space characters. So, original numbers of space characters are restored after 'join' function.

Comment: well, this is awesome. Didnt know about passing `space` character expicitly gives the required result. Thank you @Gaurav

Comment: The thing is that it parses white spaces as empty strings to the list `''` instead of `' '`

Answer (score 4):

For lines that have whitespace at the beginning and/or end, a more robust pattern is `(\S+)` to split at non-whitespace characters:

```
import re

line1 = ' 4   426.2   orange\n'
line2 = '12    82.1   apple\n'

re_S = re.compile(r'(\S+)')
items1 = re_S.split(line1)
items2 = re_S.split(line2)
print(items1)  # [' ', '4', '   ', '426.2', '   ', 'orange', '\n']
print(items2)  # ['', '12', '    ', '82.1', '   ', 'apple', '\n']
```

These two lines have the same number of items after splitting, which is handy. The first and last items are *always* whitespace strings. These lines can be reconstituted using a join with a zero-length string:

```
print(repr(''.join(items1)))  # ' 4   426.2   orange\n'
print(repr(''.join(items2)))  # '12    82.1   apple\n'
```

---

To contrast the example with a similar pattern `(\s+)` (lower-case) used in the other answer here, each line splits with different result lengths and positions of the items:

```
re_s = re.compile(r'(\s+)')
print(re_s.split(line1))  # ['', ' ', '4', '    ', '20.0', '   ', 'orange', '\n', '']
print(re_s.split(line2))  # ['12', '    ', '82.1', '   ', 'apple', '\n', '']
```

As you can see, this would be a bit more difficult to process in a consistent manner.